API Request working on iOS but not Android
Hello I have the following API Request from OpenStreetMap:
    getGeoCodePosition(lat,lng){
        
        let apiuri = apiUrl.osm+`&q=${lat},${lng}`;
        console.log(apiuri)
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'GET',    
            'User-Agent': 'Appname/1.0', 

        };
        return fetch(`${apiuri}`, requestOptions).then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
           return response.json()
        }).catch((e) => {
            console.error(e)
            return e
        })
    }

For some reason today it has stopped working on Android, but on iOS it has been working fine. This is how the API is being called:
  const handleMapPress = (event) => {
    setLoading(true)
    setDisplayName("")
    const { latitude, longitude } = event.nativeEvent.coordinate;
    setSelectedLocation({ latitude, longitude });
    GeocoderOsm.getGeoCodePosition(latitude, longitude,{ language: 'en' }).then((res) => {
      console.log("Geocode response:", res);
      if (res && res.length > 0) {
        
        setDisplayName(res[0].display_name);
        setCity(getCityName(res[0]));
        setCountry(res[0].address.country);
      } else {
        console.error("Empty response or unexpected format:", res);
      }
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.error("getGeoCodePosition error", e);
    });

setLoading(false)
  };

The response on Android:
{"_bodyBlob": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "1C1E6A83-197D-4714-9D14-5F46E2CB083B", "name": "search.php", "offset": 0, "size": 689, "type": "application/json"}}, "_bodyInit": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "1C1E6A83-197D-4714-9D14-5F46E2CB083B", "name": "search.php", "offset": 0, "size": 689, "type": "application/json"}}, "bodyUsed": false, "headers": {"map": {"content-length": "689", "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8", "date": "Thu, 31 Oct 2024 16:05:22 GMT", "server": "nginx"}}, "ok": true, "status": 200, "statusText": "", "type": "default", "url": "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?format=json&addressdetails=1&limit=20&accept-language=en&q=25.314486992672595,55.394037819195795"}

The response on iOS:
[{"address": {"ISO3166-2-lvl4": "AE-SH", "city": "Sharjah", "country": "United Arab Emirates", "country_code": "ae", "road": "72 Street", "state": "Sharjah Emirate", "suburb": "Al Khalidiyah"}, "addresstype": "road", "boundingbox": ["25.3386410", "25.3390257", "55.3720150", "55.3727268"], "class": "highway", "display_name": "72 Street, Al Khalidiyah, Sharjah, Sharjah Emirate, United Arab Emirates", "importance": 0.0533433333333333, "lat": "25.338833666809208", "licence": "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://osm.org/copyright", "lon": "55.37237031381649", "name": "72 Street", "osm_id": 392928702, "osm_type": "way", "place_id": 38375036, "place_rank": 26, "type": "residential"}]

I am not breaking any rules according to this page:
https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/
Also both devices are on the same network
I tried the API call for both android and iOS and was expecting the following:
[{"address": {"ISO3166-2-lvl4": "AE-SH", "city": "Sharjah", "country": "United Arab Emirates", "country_code": "ae", "road": "72 Street", "state": "Sharjah Emirate", "suburb": "Al Khalidiyah"}, "addresstype": "road", "boundingbox": ["25.3386410", "25.3390257", "55.3720150", "55.3727268"], "class": "highway", "display_name": "72 Street, Al Khalidiyah, Sharjah, Sharjah Emirate, United Arab Emirates", "importance": 0.0533433333333333, "lat": "25.338833666809208", "licence": "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://osm.org/copyright", "lon": "55.37237031381649", "name": "72 Street", "osm_id": 392928702, "osm_type": "way", "place_id": 38375036, "place_rank": 26, "type": "residential"}]

But the response is different on android.

Compare the HTTP request headers against each other.
